# displaying an alert box when a javascript function is executed

Tags: javascript, html, forms, popup, onsubmit

The following code gives a customized dialog box(with html,css and JS codes) created by me which is dsplayed when a button is clicked!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
/* The Modal (background) */
.modal {
    display: none; /* Hidden by default */
    position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
    z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
    padding-top: 100px; /* Location of the box */
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%; /* Full width */
    height: 100%; /* Full height */
    overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); /* Black w/ opacity */
}

/* Modal Content */
.modal-content {
    position: relative;
    background-color: #fefefe;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 0;
    border: 1px solid #888;
    width: 80%;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2),0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.19);
    -webkit-animation-name: animatetop;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 0.4s;
    animation-name: animatetop;
    animation-duration: 0.4s
}

/* Add Animation */
@-webkit-keyframes animatetop {
    from {top:-300px; opacity:0} 
    to {top:0; opacity:1}
}

@keyframes animatetop {
    from {top:-300px; opacity:0}
    to {top:0; opacity:1}
}

/* The Close Button */
.close {
    color: white;
    float: right;
    font-size: 28px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.modal-header {
    padding: 2px 16px;
    background-color: #5cb85c;
    color: white;
}

.modal-body {padding: 2px 16px;}

.modal-footer {
    padding: 2px 16px;
    background-color: #5cb85c;
    color: white;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>Animated Modal with Header and Footer</h2>

<!-- Trigger/Open The Modal -->
<button id="myBtn">Open Modal</button>

<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal">

  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <span class="close">&times;</span>
      <h2>Modal Header</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      <p>Some text in the Modal Body</p>
      <p>Some other text...</p>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <h3>Modal Footer</h3>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>

<script>
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');

// Get the button that opens the modal
var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks the button, open the modal 
btn.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "block";
}

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "none";
}

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (event.target == modal) {
        modal.style.display = "none";
    }
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

i want to display the dialog box when a condition in a javascript function is executed when a form is submitted! The following is the html code for the javascript function and the form

```
<form id=orders name="orders" action="orders_action.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" onsubmit="return test()">
   function test(){
        var element = document.getElementById("time").value;
        var d = new Date();
        var m = d.getMinutes();
        var h = d.getHours();
       if(h == '0') {h = 24}

      var currentTime = h+"."+m;
      console.log(currentTime);

      // get input time
      var time = element.split(":");
      var hour = time[0];
      if(hour == '00') {hour = 24}
      var min = time[1];

      var inputTime = hour+"."+min;
      console.log(inputTime);

      var totalTime = currentTime - inputTime;
      console.log(totalTime);

      if ((Math.abs(totalTime)) > 2) {

         document.getElementById('time').style.background ='white';



      } 
      else {
         document.getElementById('time').style.background ='#e35152';
        alert("Wrong time");

      }
    }
```

Instead of the alert box in the the above JS function i want to display "wrong time message" in the dialog box i created! how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of alert function.Write following code(Pure Js):

```
modal.style.display = "block";
modal.querySelector('.modal-body').innerHTML="<p>Wrong time</p>";
```